# Seaborn Boxplot showing dashes rather than data

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, boxplot

I have been utilizing Seaborn to create a boxplot, however it is returning a chart that solely shows dashes rather than the data present. If anyone can offer any advise it would be greatly appreciated.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import seaborn as sns
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


    UserCount = list([407, 298, 252, 338, 174, 133, 1816, 1880, 1745, 7684, 4993, 4366, 1439, 1418, 1126, 2286, 2411, 1969, 774, 739, 649])
    Function = list(["Country Risk", "Country Risk","Country Risk", "News", "News", "News", "Search", "Search", "Search", "Entity Page", "Entity Page", "Entity Page", "Corporate Hierarchy", "Corporate Hierarchy", "Corporate Hierarchy", "Financials", "Financials", "Financials","Portfolio", "Portfolio", "Portfolio"])
    Month = list(["October", "November", "December", "October", "November", "December", "October", "November", "December", "October", "November", "December", "October", "November", "December", "October", "November", "December", "October", "November", "December",])


   #Created dataframe combining three lists together
   TotalUsers = pd.DataFrame({"FC Function": Function, "Month": Month, "User Count": UserCount})

   # Draw a nested boxplot to show user count by month
   sns.set(style="ticks")
   sns.boxplot(x='Month', y= 'User Count', data=TotalUsers, hue="FC Function", palette="PRGn")
   sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
   plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A box plot "shows the distribution of quantitative data", but your grouping of `x='Month', y= 'User Count', hue="FC Function"` correspond to single points of data in `TotalUsers`.  Single points of data have no distribution so no box is drawn.

Comment: I am going to add another field to the data frame to alter the fact that there is only one point per variable. That went completely over my head, thank you for the help